# Pandas - Highlight nth subsequent equal value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to figure out how to highlight the nth subsequent value (and following ones) in a Pandas dataframe in order to obtain something like:

```
 Example 1: highlight 3rd subsequent equal value in Column A:

 Column A | Desired_output
 1        | 0
 1        | 0
 1        | 1
 1        | 1
 1        | 1
 1        | 1
 0        | 0
 0        | 0

 Example 2: highlight 5th subsequent equal value in Column A:

 Column A | Desired_output
 1        | 0
 1        | 0
 1        | 0
 1        | 0
 1        | 1
 1        | 1
 0        | 0
 0        | 0
```

This should not only work when Column A is equal to 1, but also with zeros. The main idea is: if I do not have enough subsequent equal values, my code should not take them into account.

I was thinking to use a pd.rolling_sum command with a dynamic window but I am struggling with the application, do you have any idea on how to proceed? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your piece of code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]})

# set n as the number of repetitions to highlight:
n=3 #or n=5
```

You have two different ways to deal with this:

#### Particular case

It can solve your particular problem (it demands that your column consists only of 1 and 0) and needs numpy:

```
import numpy as np

df['Desired Output']=np.where(df.rolling(n).sum()%n==0, True, False)
```

#### General case

It allows you to solve different kinds of comparisons between rows (not only checking equality), like this:

```
comparison = True

for i in range(n):
    comparison &= df['A'] == df['A'].shift(i)

df['Desired Output'] = comparison
```

#### Results for both cases

For n = 3, you will have:

```
    A   Desired Output
0   1   False
1   1   False
2   1   True
3   1   True
4   1   True
5   1   True
6   0   False
7   0   False
```

And for n=5, you will have:

```
    A   Desired Output
0   1   False
1   1   False
2   1   False
3   1   False
4   1   True
5   1   True
6   0   False
7   0   False
```

#### Format:

If you need your new column with 1 and 0, using the particular case approach, you can just use 1 and 0 instead of True and False when creating the column, like this:

```
# consider that in this scenario, a sequence of zeros it will be flagged with 1
df['Desired Output']=np.where(df.rolling(n).sum()%n==0, 1, 0)
```

If you choose to adopt the general case, just include astype(int) when creating the column, like this:

```
df['Desired Output'] = comparison.astype(int)
```

Comment: Looks neat! Thank you Joao!

Comment: I have updated my answer, now it contains a solution with rolling that you were looking for. Please, check if it address your problem.